# NodePort services not working as expected on AWS, possibly due to IAM ELB permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-elb, kubectl

#### Problem

I'm trying to create a service of type `NodePort` in my Kubernetes cluster, but it's not working as expected, and I suspect it has to do the fact that I've disabled ELB permissions for the IAM roles being used on my master node.  I wouldn't think ELB permissions should matter for `NodePort`, but I'm seeing an error message that leads me to think this.  Am I doing something wrong?  Is this a known issue others have seen before?

#### Attempt

Deployed a service of type `NodePort` to my cluster, expecting to be able to reach my service on any of the nodes' public IPs and the given port, but I can't. There's 1 master and 2 non-master nodes, and no process is even bound to port 30095 (the assigned `NodePort`) except on the master node. SSH'ing onto the master and curling that port in a variety of ways does nothing (`curl` just hangs). Curling the endpoints associated with the service works fine. `kubectl describe` on the service suggests there was some error creating a load balancer, but I don't know why it would be doing that.

I'll reiterate that I specifically disabled the IAM role used by the master nodes from being able to do any ELB things. I don't want developers using my Kubernetes cluster to be able to spin up ELB's in my account, or do anything for that matter that would create AWS resources in my account.

#### Actual Result

- information about service (commands run from local workstation) -- note `CreatingLoadBalancerFailed` error in output of `kubectl describe service`:

  ```
  $ kubectl get services frontend -oyaml
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  ---SNIP---
    ports:
    - nodePort: 30095
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
    selector:
      app: guestbook
      tier: frontend
    sessionAffinity: None
    type: NodePort
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}

  $ kubectl describe services frontend
  Name:           frontend
  Namespace:      default
  Labels:         app=guestbook
              tier=frontend
  Selector:       app=guestbook,tier=frontend
  Type:           NodePort
  IP:         100.67.10.125
  Port:           <unset> 80/TCP
  NodePort:       <unset> 30095/TCP
  Endpoints:      100.96.1.2:80,100.96.2.2:80,100.96.2.4:80
  Session Affinity:   None
  Events:
    FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From            SubObjectPath   Type            Reason              Message
    --------- --------    -----   ----            -------------   --------    ------                  -------
    1h        4m      15  {service-controller }           Warning         CreatingLoadBalancerFailed  (events with common reason combined)
  ```
- looking for processes bound to port on non-master node:

  ```
  $ netstat -tulpn | grep 30095
  # no output
  ```
- looking for processes bound to port on master node:

  ```
  $ netstat -tulpn | grep 30095
  tcp6       0      0 :::30095                :::*                    LISTEN      1540/kube-proxy
  ```
- attempting to curl the service (just hangs):

  ```
  $ curl localhost:30095
  # just hangs
  ^C

  $ curl -g -6 http://[::1]:30095
  # just hangs
  ^C

  $ curl -vvvg -6 http://[::1]:30095
  * Rebuilt URL to: http://[::1]:30095/
  * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
  *   Trying ::1...
  * Connected to ::1 (::1) port 30095 (#0)
  > GET / HTTP/1.1
  > User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
  > Host: [::1]:30095
  > Accept: */*
  >
  # just hangs after that
  ^C

  $ curl 100.67.10.125:30095
  # just hangs
  ^C
  ```
- curling an endpoint from master node (works, so the pods are running fine):

  ```
  $ curl 100.96.2.4
  <html ng-app="redis">
    <head>
  ---SNIP---
    </body>
  </html>
  ```

#### Expected Result

Expected to see the same result from curling the endpoints when curling the external IP of any of the nodes on the service's assigned `NodePort` of `30095`.

#### Additional details:

- `$ kubectl version`

  ```
  Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.1+82450d0", GitCommit:"82450d03cb057bab0950214ef122b67c83fb11df", GitTreeState:"not a git tree", BuildDate:"2016-12-14T04:09:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
  Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"4", GitVersion:"v1.4.6", GitCommit:"e569a27d02001e343cb68086bc06d47804f62af6", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-11-12T05:16:27Z", GoVersion:"go1.6.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
  ```
- GitHub issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/39214
- Mailing list post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kubernetes-dev/JNC_bk1L3iI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes does this because it assumes that a new `NodePort` service may have previously been a `LoadBalancer` service, and so it may need to clean up the cloud load balancer.  A [PR](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/34271) was opened that would fix this issue, but then closed.  In the mean time, switching IAM policy for the `master` role to have `elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers` instead of `elasticloadbalancing:*` solved the issue, i.e. the rest of the cluster including `NodePort` services work fine, but still restricts people from creating ELBs.